# CSS: Align all ul in single line which are inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div like below i need to align the 3 ul which is inside the li in single row using css.

```
<div id="printEmilCountDiv" >
            <li id="reports-print-email-count">
                <ul id="reports-print-email-count-container">
                    <li>Print count:</li>
                    <li id="printCount"></li>
                </ul>
                <ul >
                    <li>Email count:</li>
                    <li id="emailCount"></li>
                </ul>
                <ul >
                    <li>Other count:</li>
                    <li id="otherCount"></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As like this

try to this code

```css
#printEmilCountDiv, #printEmilCountDiv *{
 list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;padding:0;
}
#printEmilCountDiv ul{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; border:solid 1px red;}
```

```html
<ul id="printEmilCountDiv" >
            <li id="reports-print-email-count">
                <ul id="reports-print-email-count-container">
                    <li>Print count:</li>
                    <li id="printCount">po</li>
                </ul>
                <ul >
                    <li>Email count:</li>
                    <li id="emailCount">ec</li>
                </ul>
                <ul >
                    <li>Other count:</li>
                    <li id="otherCount"oc>oc</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

**Or this like**

```css
#printEmilCountDiv, #printEmilCountDiv *{
     list-style-type:none;
      margin:0;padding:0;
    }
    #printEmilCountDiv ul{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top; border:solid 1px red;}

 #printEmilCountDiv ul li{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

```html
    <ul id="printEmilCountDiv" >
                <li id="reports-print-email-count">
                    <ul id="reports-print-email-count-container">
                        <li>Print count:</li>
                        <li id="printCount">po</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul >
                        <li>Email count:</li>
                        <li id="emailCount">ec</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul >
                        <li>Other count:</li>
                        <li id="otherCount"oc>oc</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may remove the first `li` and replace it with `div`. Then apply a styling like;

```
ul{
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Which trims the margin. **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/t1kfce1a/)** is a demo

And you may add `float: left;` to either `ul` or `li` to align them in a row, like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/t1kfce1a/1/)**